# Remove item from QStringlist using iterator

Tags: c++, qt, iterator, qtcore, qstringlist

I am trying to iterate through a `QStringList`, printing the string, and then removing it from the list.  I can't seem to find a `QStringList` method that works!  For example:

```
for ( QStringList::Iterator it = commandList.begin(); it != commandList.end(); ++it ) {
    out << "Processed command: " << *it << endl;
    *it.erase();
}
```

gives the compiler error: **'QList::Iterator' has no member named 'erase'**

1. How would I remove the items currently pointed to by the iterator?
2. Is it safe to remove it IN the loop?  (Since the `++it` may fail if I remove an item midway through the list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another solution is the use of [QMutableStringListIterator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstringlist.html#QMutableStringListIterator-typedef), it can be used as any other iterator, but it has the method "remove" that you are looking for.

```
 QMutableStringListIterator i(list); // pass list as argument
 while (i.hasNext()) { 
     i.remove();                      // delete current item
 }
```